# Facebook graph authenticate client side and server side simultaneously?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth

Here is what I am trying to do using facebook graph on my rails site:

1. user client-side flow to get user permissions and authenticate user w/ facebook
2. send the access token received on the client-side to my server for additional processing from the server side

When I try to do this, I get an error from facebook saying I cannot authenticate the server. I am using the same token to do this that was given to me on the client side. Is there any way to authenticate the server without having the user log in using the server-side process?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this in your JavaScript:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
   location.href = '#{authenticate_path}?access_token=' + escape(response.session.access_token);
   }
 }, {perms: 'offline_access'});
```

You can then access facebook via the OAuth2 gem with the given access token:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(<app_id>, <app_secret>, :site => 'https://graph.facebook.com')
token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new client, params[:access_token]
token.get('/me')
```

Comment: Thank you! This appears to work. Here is what I tried before which did not work: access_token = client.web_server.get_access_token(
   params[:token], :redirect_uri => @facebook_settings[RAILS_ENV]['oauth_callback_url']
   ) do you have any idea why this didn't work?

Comment: with the javascript above you already have an access token. you then tried to use that access token to get another access token - which doesn't work.

Comment: I got it. One other related question, I am trying to do an ajax call to make this all happen w/ jquery. I can't pass my access token as post data. When I do this: $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/oauth/callback',
   data: {
    access_token: $access_tokens,
    stuff: "123"
   },
   );
     }
  }); I can see the params[:stuff] data but access_token is empty

Comment: what is `$access_tokens` supposed to be? you can call `FB.getSession().access_token` to get the access token.

Comment: $access_tokens is just a variable that holds the access_token. For some reason I can pass the access token as a string if I do something like data: { access_token: "2_7.sljo3jilrjlsjlsjflijsi3" } but when I say access_token: var_holding_access_token the value doesn't pass through to the server so that I can access it. I end up getting a blank value. Is the access token not a string? Do I need to turn it into one?

Comment: it definitely is a string, must be some other issue in your script, which i can't say anything about since you haven't posted it in full. also note that i used `escape` in my script, which i think had to do with the access token containing some characters that had to be escaped.

Comment: I have tested that access_token is indeed passed correctly into the method b/c I alert and it displays I just can't get the value to show up server side: function store_fb_data(access_token) {
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/oauth/callback',
   data: {
    access_token: escape(access_token),
   },
   //dataType: 'html',
   success: function(xhr, textStatus) {
      alert(xhr);
      return true;
     },
   error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('An error occurred trying to log into ignition.' + 
      ( errorThrown ? errorThrown : xhr.status));
     }
  });
 }